# How to "expand" text in Vim, into a nice to read way?

Tags: ruby, vim, text

I work a lot with nested data structures, and many times I have to manually analyze them from the console. The problem is that they come printed all in one line.

Is there an easy way of re-structuring the display of a data structure based on `{,[,],}` and the comma, such that it will look like Ruby's pretty_print output?

Comment: How is that related to emacs and vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/\([{,]\)/\1\r/g
ggVG=
:set ft=ruby
```

wheeeee

Comment: Nice!! Worked perfectly. +1 for the response in vim!

Comment: You can omit the capturing and use `\0` or even better `&` for the whole match in the replacement: `:%s/[{,]/&\r/g`